# No deployment options in ios 4.2 xcode 3.2.5

Tags: iphone, target

Yes I'm a newbie, but not a total knob, just feel like one at the moment.

Running ios 4.2 xcode 3.5

Application runs fine on my iphone, but want to test it against iphones with an older IOS.

My settings in xcode are:

```
Project -> Set Active Architecture -> armv6
Project -> Set Active SDK -> Device
Project -> Set Active Build Configuration -> Release

Under project settings (Architectures)
    Base SDK set to 4.2 all configurations
```

In my Project Settings, I see 3 sections: Architecture, Build Locations, and Build Options.  No sign of deployment options anywhere.

Anybody have any idea why I wouldn't see a deployment target option?

Pulling my hair out.  **Any advice appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Should be under Project Settings > Build > Deployment > iOS Deployment Target

Edit to clarify: this setting tells the compiler what the OLDEST version of iOS you want to support in your app. for instance if you select 3.0, your app should run for any device with iOS 3.0 and newer.

Comment: I may be blind, but I under proj settings -> build, I only see 3 sections (architectures, Build locations, and Build Options).  No sign of deployment anywhere.  Thanks for the quick reply, any other ideas?

Comment: Those are the first three sections..there are quite a few more.. and deployment is one of those..

Comment: Unfortunately, those are the only three sections showing up on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem finding the deployment options aswell, but finally found them. You should try and expand all sections, a scrollbar will show up where you can scroll down and check all other sections (like deployment) :)